# Capybara first() only works when I add :minimum=>1

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing, cucumber, capybara

`first()` was working in version `2.15.0` as expected, but after updating `cucumber 2.4.0` to `3.1.2` it doesn't work this way anymore.

`first()` works if we add the param `:minimum=>1` to it. If I leave it out, it will return `nil` even though the element is there.

```
first("div", :minimum=>1)
```

This is our Capybara dependencies in the gemfile.lock

> capybara (2.15.0)
>         addressable
>         mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
>         nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
>         rack (>= 1.0.0)
>         rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
>         xpath (~> 2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in Capybara Upgrading.md - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#finders - the behavior of `first` changed between Capybara 2.x and 3.x -  `first` would return nil immediately in 2.x if an element didn't immediately exist when the method was called.  In 3.x it will wait for at least one matching element to exist.  It sounds like one of the libraries you've updated is expecting the Capybara 3.x behavior, so look at what else you updated when upgrading cucumber (maybe `site_prism` if you're using that too??)

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I will check which library that is now

Comment: @Nils_e Did you figure out what is expecting the Capybara 3.x behavior?